# Combining Array Values (strings) from two different arrays

Tags: ruby

I have to arrays that I would like to combine. For example:

`["a", "b", "c", "d"]` is one array
`["xxxx", "xx", "xxxxx", "x"]` is another

My desired output would be a new array that would look like this:

```
["axxxx", "bxx", "cxxxxx", "dx"]
```

I'm not quite sure how to combine these two.

Much appreciated.

Comment: zip them and join pairs

Comment: You really need to show code demonstrating you've tried to solve this problem yourself. See http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = ["a", "b", "c", "d"].zip ["xxxx", "xx", "xxxxx", "x"]
#=> [["a", "xxxx"], ["b", "xx"], ["c", "xxxxx"], ["d", "x"]] 

s.map &:join
# => ["axxxx", "bxx", "cxxxxx", "dx"]
```